# Javascript text Array Data Scrambling and Descrambling

Tags: javascript, encryption, encoder, decoder, scramble

I am looking for super fast and compact Javascript code or function to scramble and descramble text stored in Arrays.

I only want this text not readable when the user go into "View Source" mode with the browser.

There are many options like add fixed numbers to the ASCII code or do some boolean calculation on the string like shifting, reversing, change to octal, hex etc.

I need this both for text and number strings. It would be best if the scrambled code where not to complex and not with sign like ", ', #, $, &, / etc.

```
var c = new Array();
c[0]=new Array( "Name","Home","City","Post code","Telephone","email","Web","Id","Number","xpos","ypos");
c[1]=new Array( "John","Street 123","1234","New York","555-1450123","john@demo.com","www.demo1.com","b",59,306380,565500);
c[2]=new Array( "Poul","Street 1234","2345","New York","555-7010123","poul@demo.com","www.demo2.com","i",113,308396,635477);
c[3]=new Array( "David","Street 12345","3456","New York","555-3111123","david@demo.com","www.demo3.com","i",129,377615,581358);

var Scrambler = function(n) { return ASCII(n)+1...; }
var DeScrambler = function(n) { return ASCII(n)-1...; }

$(function() {
for (var i = 0; i < c[0].length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (c.length); ++i) {
        a[j][i] = DeScrambler(c[j][i]);
        }   
    }
});
```

Any good idea?

Comment: Minifying the code? There's no good way to _hide_ data that you've already sent to the user. If you really need this hidden - consider moving it to the server side.

Comment: Thanks mishik for a quick replay. I am fully aware of this issue. First, I just don't want the html code to be directly readable by the user, second for small project I don't want to use PHP or database. Third, I am more thinking about writing one code that fits to all devices like desktop, tablet computers and mobile phones and can easily be converted by services like Phonegap. But they are manly based on CSS, HTML and Javascript. And the last one I just want to find out what kind of simple scrambling people are using today.

Comment: "First, I just don't want the html code to be directly readable by the user" - not possible.
"Third, .... " - how is this relevant? Minified code does not change the script logic in _any_ way.

Comment: "First" I know, this is just to scramble the quick view of the code. "third" I think there is a possibility to write one code that fits all devices, by changing the whole structure of the code. I am trying to develop a way so you don't have to rewrite the code when going from desktop to table and mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

How about [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), ROT47, or some other substitution cipher? It's simple to implement, fast, and doesn't increase the length of the string.

Comment: I had a quick look on ROT13. I think it fits perfectly for what I am looking for like: 

`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm`

Would also be nice to have option to input different password to get the code back.

Answer (score 0):

If you are scramble the text the user will be able to see the data being transmitted. If you only want to use JS and make it universal perhaps have the server send that data as UTF8 bytes? Also this does not fall under encryption. Encryption and Obfuscation are not the same. I provided a link to a github file that does base and data type conversions. I assume you where looking for something like this.

https://github.com/CubanAzcuy/JSBytes/blob/master/Format.js

(All Byte to UTF8 String Operations are done as unsigned bytes)
(I agree with @mishik minify(ing) your code is one of the best ways to obfuscate)

Comment: Thanks _CubanAzcuy_. I also found this link: [cryptii.com/text/rot13](http://cryptii.com/text/rot13) here showing some nice text converting done by Javascript  - They show different way of converting like: **ALPHABET** (Text, Flipped Text, HTML Entitles, Morse code), **NUMERIC** (Decimal, Binary, Octal, Hexadecimal), **CIPHER** (ATBASH ROMAN, CASEAR CIPHER, ITA2 / CCITT-2, PIGPEN CIPHER, ROT5, ROT13, ROT18, ROT47), **ENCODING** (BASE64), **HASH** (MD5, SHA1).  

I think I will choose ROT18, but it convert numbers to.

Answer (score 0):

I made this working solution to solve my problem:

There are few things in this code I would like to work out better if possible.

1) In line 33 I have to use this dirty trick `""+c[i][j])` to convert number in Array to string. But when going back the problem is number is not number anymore in my array! This is very fast but if you have any better idea without loosing the number definition then pls. let me know.
2) I am using 2 version ROT13 and ROT18. I found ROT13 one-line-code version: `s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});`  How can I add numbers and -_@ letters to those ROT13 in a simple way?
3) As you can see I am using 2D Array to store my code. Any better suggestion?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var AscII = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@.-";
    var ROT18 = "STUVWXYZ0123456789@.-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR";
    var c = new Array();
    c[0]=new Array( "Name","Home","City","Post code","Telephone","email","Web","Id","Number","xpos","ypos");
    c[1]=new Array( "John","Street 123","1234","New York","438-1450123","john@demo.com","www.demo1.com","b",59,306380,565500);
    c[2]=new Array( "Poul","Street 1234","2345","New York","450-7010123","poul@demo.com","www.demo2.com","i",113,308396,6354772);
    c[3]=new Array( "David","Street 12345","3456","New York","451-3111123","david@demo.com","www.demo3.com","i",129,377615,581358);

$(function() {

    var Normal = function() {
        var txt ="";
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < c[0].length; ++j) {
                txt += ""+c[i][j] + ", ";
                }
            txt += "<br>";
            }
        $("#kData").html("<b>Normal ASCII<br></b>" + txt);
        };

    var Convert18 = function(Div, TxtFrom, TxtTo) {
        var txt ="";
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < c[0].length; ++j) {
                var ktxtX = decode((""+c[i][j]), TxtFrom, TxtTo);
                c[i][j] = ktxtX;
                txt += ktxtX + ", ";
                }
            txt += "<br>";
            }
        $(Div).html("<b>ROT18 + Numbers + @-_<br></b>" + txt);
        };

    var Convert13 = function(Div) {
        var txt ="";
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
            for (var j = 0; j < c[0].length; ++j) {
                var ktxtX = rot13(""+c[i][j]);
                // s.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,function(c){return String.fromCharCode((c<="Z"?90:122)>=(c=c.charCodeAt(0)+13)?c:c-26);});
                c[i][j] = ktxtX;
                txt += ktxtX + ", ";
                }
            txt += "<br>";
            }
        $(Div).html("<b>ROT13<br></b>" + txt);
        };

    var decode = function (txt, alphabet, substitution) {
      return txt.split("").map(function (c) {
        if (alphabet.indexOf(c) != -1) { return substitution.charAt(alphabet.indexOf(c)); }
          else { return c; }
      }).join("");
    };

    function rot13(str) {
      return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c) {
        return String.fromCharCode((c <= 'Z' ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? c : c - 26);
      });
    }

Normal();
Convert18("#kData2", AscII, ROT18);
Convert18("#kData3", ROT18, AscII);
Convert13("#kData4");
Convert13("#kData5");
$("#kData6").html("Finised - j:" + c[0].length + " - i:" + c.length);

});

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="kData"></div>
    <div id="kData2"></div>
    <div id="kData3"></div>
    <div id="kData4"></div>
    <div id="kData5"></div>
    <div id="kData6"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I put copy of the code on http://jsfiddle.net/kpsphoto/b7MaQ/